# Nearest neighbor on a unit sphere, with roughly evenly distributed points

Tags: geometry, nearest-neighbor

I'm writing a program that implements SCVT (Spherical Centroidal Voronoi Tesselation).  I start with a set of points distributed over the unit sphere (I have an option for random points or an equal-area spiral).  There will be from a several hundred to maybe 64K points.

I then need to produce probably several million random sample points, for each sample find the nearest point in the set, and use that to calculate a "weight" for that point.  (This weigh may have to be looked up from another spherical set, but that set will stay static for any given run of the algorithm.)

Then I move the original points to the calculated points, and iterate the process, probably 10 or 20 times.  This will give me the centers of the Voronoi tiles for subsequent use.

Later I will need to find a given point's nearest neighbor, to see what tile the user clicked on.  This is trivially solved within the above problem, and doesn't need to be super-fast anyway.  The part I need to be efficient is all those millions of nearest neighbors on the unit sphere.  Any pointers?

Oh, I'm using x, y, z coordinates, but that's not set in stone.  It just looks like it will simplify things.  I'm also using C as I'm most familiar with it, but not wedded to that choice either.  :)

I've considered using the spiral pattern for the sample points, as that gives me at least the last point's found neighbor as a good starting point for the next search.  But if I do that, it looks like it would make any sort of tree search useless.

edit:
[I'm sorry, I thought I was clear with the title and tags.  I can generate random points easily.  The issue is the nearest neighbor search.  What's an efficient algorithm when all the points are on the unit sphere?]

Comment: What exactly are you asking - do you want to know how to generate points randomly distributed on a sphere, or how to calculate the nearest neighbor on a spherical surface, or something else? It's not really clear.

Answer (score 3):

Your points are uniformly distributed over the sphere. Therefore, it would make a lot of sense to convert them to spherical coordinates and discretize. Searching the 2D grid first would narrow down the choice of nearest neighbour to a small part of the sphere in constant time.

Comment: I've been struck by an idea to reduce it almost another dimension.  If I arrange the points along a curve spiraling at constant distance from the previous winding, the search can be nearly linear.  Probably only have to check 2 short ranges on the line...

Answer (score 1):

You may find that organising your points into a data structure called an Octree is useful for efficient search for nearby points. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree

Answer (score 1):

I have devised a curve (I'm sure I'm not the 1st) that spirals along the sphere from pole to pole.  It remains a constant distance from neighboring windings (if I did it right).  For `z` (`-1` at south pole to `+1` at north pole):

```
n = a constant defining a given spiral
k = sqrt(n * pi)

r = sqrt(z^2)
theta = k * asin(z)
x = r * cos(theta)
y = r * sin(theta)
```

It makes `k/2` revolutions around the sphere, with each winding `sqrt(4pi/n)` from adjacent windings, while the slope `dz/d(x,y)` is `1/k`.

Anyway, set `k` such that the inter-winding distance covers the largest tile on the sphere.  For every point in the main set, calculate the `theta` of the nearest point on the curve, and index the list of points by those numbers.  For a given test point, calculate it's (`theta` of the nearest point on the curve), and find that in the index.  Search outward (in both directions) from there, to `theta` values that are as far away as your current nearest neighbor.  After reaching that limit, if the distance to that neighbor is less than the distance from the test point to the next adjacent winding, you've found the nearest neighbor.  If not, jump the `theta` value by `2pi` and search that winding the same way.

Critique?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article on neighbor search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search
In my understanding you can use trivial algorithm of going through all Voronoi centers and calculate 3d distance between your point and center point.

```
distance_2 = (x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 + (z - z_0)^2
```

where (x_0, y_0, z_0) is the point of interest (click) for you and {(x, y, z)} are Voronoi centers. The smallest distance will give you the nearest center.

Comment: This is basically the worst-case algorithm, O(n), requiring you to scan through all the points for each test point.  For the user interface code, this would probably be acceptable.  For the many millions of sampling points, an O(logn) method (or less) would be much preferred.

Comment: @Jerry B, still it could be worse. O(n) isn't bad.

Comment: Well, that's O(n) for each search, making the whole algorithm O(n*m).  That's approaching a trillion comparisons.  Since scanning the whole list is the "naive" method, I don't see how it could be done worse without doing so on purpose.

Comment: Then I probably got you wrong. I thought that you had 64K points, after that selected some small amount of Voronoi centers (I assumed less than 100) and then for only one point (mouse click) you need to find a nearest group, i.e. nearest Voronoi center.

Comment: if your points are in a relational database, just add a where clause to limit the points selected to only those roughly close enough to be considered for the O(n) calculation, as proposed. I was looking for similar colours in a L*a*b* sphere like this and it was really fast.

Comment: Artem: I start with up to 64K points & for the many sample points find the nearest point in the that set. Calculate a weighted distance between them & running total that for each of the 64K points.  This determines where the points of the 64K set move to.  Later, I will also need the mouse clicks.

Comment: MasterPeter: So far, the points are just in an array in memory. 

For *illions of samples against up to 64K points, that's still going to take a lot of time.  This is to generate a map for a game, and I don't think people will want to wait minutes, let alone hours, to start playing.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a KD Trie is a good way to speed up the search. You can also get significantly better performance if you can tolerate some error. The [ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/) library will give you the result within an ε of your choosing.

Comment: No, ANN wouldn't work.  To calculate the centroid with any accuracy requires exact NN.  Does a KD Trie handle the points being on the unit sphere well?  The Wiki page on KD Tries mentions ANN, but not NN.

I may have to do an ANN, followed by a search of the nearby points for the exact NN.

Comment: The ε can be zero, if necessary. Although, then there is a wider choice of implementations available, and the ANN library is not necessarily the best one. It has the huge drawback of not being thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

OK. NEARPT3 http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/nearpt3/nearpt3.pdf algorithm could be helpful in your case. And it all depends on how many space you can afford to use for your N points. If it is O(N*logN) then there are algorithms like kD-tree based (http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/inf2b/learnnotes/inf2b-learn06-lec.pdf) which would work for O(logN) to find nearest point. In case of 64K point Nlog_2 N = about 10^6 which is easily can fit into memory of modern computer.

Comment: Some good reading there.  One thing that struck me in the lecture notes was the comment that time tends to go exponentially by dimension.  Thus, the kD-tree in 3 dimensions seems wasteful for what is essentially 2 dimensional data.  Otherwise, it sounds nice.

Comment: Right. However, you want to be careful, because the nearest neighbour in spherical coordinates is not necesserily the nearest neighbour in Cartesian.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, simpler than creating a quad-tree, is using a **neighborhood matrix**.

First place all your points into a 2D square matrix (by converting the points to polar coordinates). Then you can run a full or partial spatial sort, so points will became ordered inside the matrix.

Points with small Y (or phi) could move to the top rows of the matrix, and likewise, points with large Y would go to the bottom rows. The same will happen with points with small X (or theta) coordinates, that should move to the columns on the left. And symmetrically, points with large X value will go to the right columns.

After you did the spatial sort (there are many ways to achieve this, both by serial or parallel algorithms) you can lookup the nearest points of a given point P by just visiting the adjacent cells where point P is actually stored in the neighborhood matrix.

You can read more details for this idea in the following paper (you will find PDF copies of it online): *Supermassive Crowd Simulation on GPU based on Emergent Behavior*.

The sorting step gives you interesting choices. You can use just the even-odd transposition sort described in the paper, which is very simple to implement (even in CUDA). If you run just one pass of this, it will give you a partial sort, which can be already useful if your matrix is near-sorted. That is, if your points move slowly, it will save you a lot of computation.

If you need a full sort, you can run such even-odd transposition pass several times (as described in the following Wikipedia page):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd%E2%80%93even_sort

Comment: Ouch.  That hurts to read.  I assume either the paper was written in Portuguese then translated to English (badly), or the author's English itself is atrocious.

Comment: That aside, 2-dimensional sorting really doesn't make sense in most cases.  If you do as he does, alternating passes in X & Y, then each pass potentially (and likely) destroys any guarantee of sortedness from the prior pass in the other direction.  That means even a full `N` passes in each direction doesn't guarantee any sortedness.  In fact, it's not even clear what sortedness would **mean** in 2 dimensions (similar to the inability to order complex numbers).

And if you do a full sort in 1 direction followed by a full sort in the other, the 1st sort is essentially redundant.

Comment: @jerry, in fact you are sorting pairs, however changing the importance order for each direction. So, when you sort the columns, you compare first by X and if they match, compare by Y. For the rows it is similar, but you compare first by Y and then by X, if necessary. The sorting code is really similar to the Odd Even Sort in Wikipedia, but with four double-loops (even columns, odd columns, even rows and odd rows).

I've implemented it by myself, and it works. But, of course, the complexity is O(n²), because you may need several passes to sort it all.

Comment: I've placed the code I used in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ELJwUehy). Also, I've grabbed to sample images, where the points are color coded by red (X) and green (Y). So you have the initial state, completely random in [before](http://picpaste.com/before.png). After calling `partial_sort()` 10 times, I got [after](http://picpaste.com/after.png).

Comment: Of course, as the matrix is like a compaction, the more uniformly you have the point set, the better the sorted arrangement. For my specific application (a tight particle simulation), this works very well. But if you have large empty areas or very dense clusters in your dataset, the result won't be very good (but you would have the same problems when using spatial hashing). In fact, I was previously using spatial hashing in CUDA but wasted to much time re-sorting the buckets (when particles moved from one to another). This solution fits perfectly for me (even more using texture-mem lookups).